# Make a function that presses a key on the keyboard in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am making a Game in Unity and to Jump I am ussing the Spacebar. Now I have a little glitch that doesn't show the Jump Animation when I press Spacebar. I figured out when I double tab Spacebar the Animation shows perfectly. So is there a way that the Jump function that gets executed when I click the Spacebar automaticly makes another Spacebar hit so it does the double tab but I only have to do one tap on the keyboard?

Comment: Will it not be better to fix the bug of the animation not playing than to hack an extra press into the game

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html Maybe this is what you're looking for? :)

So basically at any point in your animation you're able to insert a function